# How to use one to many relation query in parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

I have the 2 classes one is post and other is comments
=> One post has many comments

And i want to result like this

results:[ {
           post_title:'post1',
           date:'..',
           postcomments:[
                        {comment1},
                        {comment2},...]
          },
          {
           post_title:'post2',
           date:'..',
           postcomments:[
                        {comment1},
                        {comment2},...]
          }
        ]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but rather than try to build something on parse.com, I suggest that you put your energy into moving off the platform. It's [closing next January](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use Lists: The `Post` object has a property `postcomments` that is a list of `Comment` objects. You could query then as follows (javascript):

```
new Parse.Query("Comment")
    .include("postcomments")
```

This will give you a list of `Post` objects. Each `Post` object will have a list of associated `Comment` objects which you can access like this: `post.get("postcomments")`

If you expect to usually have more than 100 or so comments for one post you can also use Parse relations. The advantage here is that the comments are not always fetched together with the post thus saving data.

Comment: AFAIK, list of Parse Objects will contains list of pointers.  Another way is maintaining the array of jsonObjects which contains message, commentor and so on.

Comment: Yes, it contains pointers. You can either fetch those one by one or by using the `include` flag when querying the post(s)

Comment: can you please write the query?